# SignalR not working correctly after deployment on windows server 2012

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, signalr, iis-8.5

I am facing issues in live environment. When ever a ever a page is loaded signal r connection is created but connectionids of other connects are not available for the new connectionids and also for old connectionId this newly created connection is not available. To make it better understand see the code below

My method in chathub.vb which is called from server side

```
Public Sub getGonnected()

    Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).hello("Connection is connected CONNECTIONID = " + Context.ConnectionId)

    Dim heartBeat = GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve(Of ITransportHeartbeat)()
    Dim connectionAlive = heartBeat.GetConnections().Where(Function(c) c.ConnectionId <> Context.ConnectionId).ToList()
    Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).hello("Other Connections Available ..............................................................")
    For Each item In connectionAlive
        Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).hello(".................................................................. " + item.ConnectionId)
    Next
    Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).hello("End of other connections available ........................................................")
    Clients.All.hello("Total Number of users available ..................................................................")
    Clients.All.hello("........................................................................... " + connectionAlive.Count().ToString())
    Clients.All.hello("End total Number of users available ...............................................................")
End Sub
```

And in my clients side

```
   chat.client.hello = function(ping)
        {
            console.log(ping);
        }
 $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
   });
   setInterval(function () {

                chat.server.getGonnected().done(function (result) {
                    console.log('connectionRequestsent')
                });

        }, 5000);
```

Also in my web.config I have added following settings

target framework 4.5

As per above example code above

I am not able to see a new connection in the borwsers console when some new user registers will signalr. And also that new user is unable to see the ConnectionId's of already present users in signalr in the browser console.

This thing is only happening on server. An help would be much appretiated. I have already enabled websockets and my websockets handshake is successfull. Moreover the spefic conntectionId is able to send and recieve messages to and from server. But not with other connectionId as the are not availble.

In simple words some times

```
 Dim connectionAlive = heartBeat.GetConnections().Where(Function(c) 
 c.ConnectionId <> Context.ConnectionId).ToList()
```

Length is 0 where as there are already other connections in the app. Which I am not sure why is happening.

Any help or guidance will be much appreciated.

SignalR version is 2.1.0

Regards

Abdul

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with WIndows Server 2012. You will have to implement this yourself in either a dictionary, database or something else suitable to your situation.

Using the OnConnect event, you can broadcast to every currently connected client an update that someone has joined or with the OnDisconnect that someone has left as well. If you want it to be a list of currently connected users you would query your dictionary/database/else... and broadcast.

[SignalR Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections) has some examples.

Comment: Yes I do understand that.
and OnConnected and OnReconnected I am saving connectionIds against the users in database

But then when I call 


    `Clients.Client(getUser.ConnectionId).unreadMessages(unreadMessageCount, queryId)`
                    `Clients.Client(getUser.ConnectionId).supportAgentRecieveMessage(queryId, message)`

It fails to send message to other user. Even though the other user is connected.

Comment: Check the docs... I believe you should be using Clients.User: 

    public void Send(string userId, string message)
    {
        Clients.User(userId).send(message);
    }

Comment: I have read those documentation. And every thing works as expected on local machine. I also tested on another windows server 2012 machine and it was working fine. But on our production windows server machine I am facing the issue. So I need help regarding if there are some security settings or network settings that is not letting the signal r to work as expected. Unfortunately I don't have access to that server but I have to dig into myself what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Download working signalr project at https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-samples from the developer
After downloading select any of the examples in the directory which you will run through your visual studio.
I select ChatSample run and follow the on-screen instruction
After that go through the documentation to read through each files how it works at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/

Answer (score 0):

Please install the latest version of .Net Framework, in my case this solve the problem, I installed 4.8 and all broadcast messages were sent.